# CefSharp Browser control not working with Azure AD Conditional access

Tags: azure-active-directory, chromium, cefsharp

We configured our Azure AD application registration to use “Conditional Access” restrictions to lock down the application to machines that are registered to the domain.  Unfortunately, in order to successfully authenticate with Conditional Access enabled on chromium based browsers, a browser extension is required

There is quite a bit of documentation around this on Microsoft’s website

•   [Conditional Access require managed device - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/require-managed-devices)
•   [Conditions in Conditional Access policy - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-conditions)

when the user trying to log in with cefsharp browser control we see the following error. Tried enabling the browser extension did not help [image]

Comment: Your best bet is to ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php As CEF only supports a subset of the chromium extension API it's u likely your extension will work. https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Sadly CefSharp will not work with Device Management policy.

To prove device identity on Windows, the Windows broker (WAM) needs to intercept the network traffic and inject the device id. The following browsers are supported: Edge, old IE, Chrome with Windows Accounts extension and I'm not sure about Firefox.

Since CefSharp is based on Chromium but does not have the extension (and, afaik, there is no way to install it), WAM cannot inject the device ID in the requests made to AAD.

Possible workaround:

- use WebView2 SDK on Windows, which is based on Edge, which is also based on Chromium... At the time of writing, Mac support is planned but not released.
  And use Cef on Mac and Linux.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by inject the device ID? Is it just a simple http header that's added to the request? Is it the MSAL library that's used to obtain a device ID for us apps and desktop apps?

Comment: Only a low level OS component can certify that a device is "managed" (i.e. domain joined / Intuned). MSAL library or any other library cannot access this information. Not exactly sure where WAM injects the device ID, but it works by intercepting network traffic.

Comment: This is the strategy on Mac as well. A component called SSO Extension intercepts traffic to AAD and injects the device ID. I believe this was done for security purposes, otherwise any app could inject a (possibly fake) device ID in a request.

Comment: What exactly is a low level OS component in this context? If the functionality is implemented in Chrome as an extension I would expect it's limited to the Chrome extension api. Plus as it's an extension you should be able to extract the crx file and view the JavaScript. I appreciate that security is of the utmost importance. There are businesses out there that already have a great deal invested in their current solutions. WebView2 is still relatively immature, from what I can gather the backlog of tasks/features for the project is a very long list.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There are gaps in how AAD supports various browsers for sure. Note that the CA policy is controlled by the tenant admin, not by Microsoft. For public client applications, AAD suggests you integrate directly with WAM or that you pop up a system browser.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of this issue and complexity behind it, I had to migrate off CefSharp to use the new WebView2 browser component until there is a supported approach released for CefSharp and other third-party browsers to inject logic like the code below. The EdgeWebView2 works by enabling the SSO flag ***get_AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount***

C# .NET example code below using the EdgeWebView2 browser component (as of writing this is the only way I know to defeat the authentication message "**You can't get there from here**"):

```
CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions envOptions = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions()
{
    AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = true
};
CoreWebView2Environment env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(options: envOptions).Result;
webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
webview.Source = new Uri("https://portal.azure.com/");
```